# Limiting the number of data to send from userform to excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a program that would add employees from the userform to the Excel sheet. By using the Offset property, I can add employees to the next range of cells. But how do I limit the number of employees I can add? Like if I have already employed 10 employees (limit is 10 employees) then I have entered a data in userform so I can employ the 11th employee, a msgbox will appear and data would not send to excel sheet. I have tried an `If` condition statement but doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA() function to count all employee names you entered.
For example,

```
' Change "Sheet1" and "A1:A20" to match your sheet name and employee name column
if Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")) = 10 then
    Msgbox "Employee name exeeded the limit."
    exit sub
endif
```